# How to Disable Save As dialog in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, firefox, cross-browser

How to disable Save As dialog while pressing Ctrl+S

Description: I am developing one web application.Here When i am going to form submitting  using "Ctrl+S",In Firefox before submitting "save As dialog" will open.How to disable save As dialog in Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by handling the window's `onkeypress` event to check whether the `CTRL` key and `S` are depressed, and if so, canceling the event from by calling `preventDefault()` on the event object:

```
window.onkeypress = function(event) {
    if (event.charCode === 115 && event.ctrlKey) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // your code here....
        alert("'Save As' dialog suppressed!");
    }
};
```

Note that the keypress event may behave differently in different browsers.  This did work in FireFox, however.